# ajax get to 3rd party server within express middleware results in 500 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, html, express

I have a requirement to access multiple devices over IP from an HTML5 web app.

My approach to working around the cross-domain impossibility of doing this all on the client side has been to "cook" requests from the client inside of express' middleware. A route receives a get or post from the client, and then performs a get or post to the 3rd party device identified by the payload from the client.

I'm using the code to get info from a device. It works just fine when I run it directly from file inside of a client I made for testing purposes. Running directly from file avoids the CORS difficulty because the client is also the server I guess.

When I run the same code from within an express route, I get a 500 error.

Am I trying to do something impossible? I'm only about a week into node, express etc so hopefully it's something dumb and easy to solve.  I'm taking fact that I haven't been able to find any other questions quite like this as an indication that there's a proper way to achieve what I need.

```
// post to find a camera
router.post('/find', function(req, res) {
    var url = 'http://' + req.body.addr + '/cgi-bin/aw_cam?cmd=QID&res=1';
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (result) {
        console.log('success: ' + result);
        res.send(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
            console.log('error: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's what logged to the server console:

```
http://192.168.0.10/cgi-bin/aw_cam?cmd=QID&res=1
POST /cameras/find 500 126.593 ms - 1656
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ok I found how to do this. The trick is to use Node's built-in http messaging capabilities. I found a good article on how to do this [here](https://davidwalsh.name/nodejs-http-request)

The code below does exactly what I wanted from within my custom route middleware. I guess I just learned that I can only use AJAX how I wanted on the client side.

This lets me abstract the hairier details of the device control protocol into the server, leaving my client apps to use JSON/AJAX model to interact with them. Success!

```
var http = require('http');
// post to find a camera
router.post('/find', function(req, res) {
    var url = 'http://' + req.body.addr + '/cgi-bin/aw_cam?cmd=QID&res=1';
    console.log(url);

    http.get(url, (response) => {
        console.log(`Got response: ${response.statusCode}`);
        var body = '';
        response.on ('data', function(d) {
            body += d;
        });
        response.on ('end', function () {
            console.log('received: ' + body);
            var reply = {};
            if (body.indexOf('OID:') == 0) {
                reply.msg = body.slice(4);
                reply.ok = true;
            } else {
                reply.msg = body;
                reply.ok = false;
            }
            res.send(reply);
        });
        // consume response body
        response.resume();
    }).on('error', (e) => {
        console.log(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
    });
});
```